# How to limit access to specific path in public folder for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I would like to limit access to `public/templates/sb-admin-2`path within my Laravel application.

Adding this template was part of the steps in order to setup 
[antonioribeiro/tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) package. now `<MyDomain>/templates/sb-admin-2`is taking me to the template without any authentication. It doesn't make sense to let any user to access this template in production. How can I limit the access so users would not be able to access the template?

Thanks

Comment: add auth middleware to the route...

Comment: shouldn't you be putting these kind of files in `resource` directory.

Comment: nice question, shame you didn't get any better answers; this can probably be done via the webserver config (apache, nginx, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR;

**don't.**

The word `public` truly ought to mean public. Whatever is placed there, should be accessible to everyone. Plus, Laravel (server) will FIRST check the filesystem, if no file found, then it will ask PHP to interpret the request.

**But...**

...you may faux the behavior by placing the files in a separate directory, and then release the files via php, for example:

First, rename `public/templates/sb-admin-2` to `public/xcscxcsx` (for example). That way any time anyone asking for the *templates* folder, will have to go through Laravel.

Second, make a Route that will check Auth and either return the contents of asked file, or will deny access.

```
Route::get('/templates/sb-admin-2/{path?}', function () {
    if(\Auth::check()) {
        // 21 = characters count of "templates/sb-admin-2"
        $newPath = substr(ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), 21);
        return \File::get(
            public_path('xcscxcsx/' . $newPath)
        );
    }
    return 'access denied';
})->where(['path' => '.*']);
```

---

Problems:

- All files will be available. For example:
  `/templates/sb-admin-2/.gitignore` will be displayed on screen.
- Anyone knowing about the existence of `xcscxcsx` will still have
  access to the files. So maybe put them inside `storage` folder, and
  go with `storage_path` parsing

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.4 for your webserver you can use the following directive to whitelist your IP(s) and prevent others from accessing the directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/MyDomain/public/templates/sb-admin-2>
    Require ip 192.168.0.1
</Directory>
```

Just swap in your IP in place of `192.168.0.1`. You can add multiple IP addresses to the whitelist with the following syntax:

```
Require ip 192.168.1.104 192.168.1.205
```

Read more about Apache 2.4 Access Control here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html